# How do I improve this checkbox list to make sure that some of the text did not sit under the checkbox?

Tags: html, css

How do I improve this list of checkbox to make sure that all the same text sit and appears on the same line ?

my current checkbox looks like this

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is I want this kind of checkbox list

```
[] Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
   elit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
[] Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
   elit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
[] Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
   elit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
```

instead of like this

```
[] Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
lit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
[] Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
lit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
[] Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
lit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
```

```html
<p><input type="checkbox"> Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
<p><input type="checkbox"> We always provide people a complete solution focused of any business.Change in the volume of expected sales Change in the volume of expected sales </p>
<p><input type="checkbox"> Change in the volume of expected sales </p>
<p><input type="checkbox"> Change in the volume of expected sales </p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your `input` tags and the text are direct children of the `p` tag. You need to separate the `input` tags from the `p` tags. For example,

```html
<input type="checkbox" /><p>Your text here</p>
```

Perhaps its better to wrap the above code in a `div` or a `span` like this.

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <p>Your text here</p>
</div>
```

Or what you can do is make the `p` tag a flex/inline-flex.

```css
p {
    display: flex
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the display of the `p` tag to use a flex display.

```css
p {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="checkbox"> Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
<p><input type="checkbox"> We always provide people a complete solution focused of any business.Change in the volume of expected sales Change in the volume of expected sales </p>
<p><input type="checkbox"> Change in the volume of expected sales </p>
<p><input type="checkbox"> Change in the volume of expected sales </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the `<input>` tags outside of the `p` tags. So the markup would look like this.

```
<input type="checkbox"><p>Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
```

Then you can adjust the CSS such that the `<p>` elements are always to the right of the checkboxes.